# How to duplicate a qr code from a member card

Tags: qr-code

I have some member cards with a QR code printed on them. How can I read the code, and then generate the exact same QR code, so I can have the picture of the code and attach it to other documents.

I've tried app qr readers, and online qr generators, but it always generates a different qr code.

Thanks!

Comment: Just treat it as any other image you want to copy.

Comment: But I can't get an enough clear image, even with scanners or digital cameras.

Comment: So maybe do some research into image enhancement (sharpening / contrast adjustment).

Comment: I actually tried it, but it takes too much if I have too much membercards. Thanks anyway!